# Consuming Json data ProcessRequest winrt

Tags: c#, json, web-services, windows-runtime, overriding

I am working on consuming Json data in Windows RT. I followed steps from this [link](http://www.bartlannoeye.com/blog/consuming-json-data-in-winrt) as follows

```
protected override HttpRequestMessage ProcessRequest(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    if(request.Method==HttpMethod.Get)
    {
        request.Headers.Add("abcustom", "reqvalue");
    }
    return request;
 }
```

But, at `ProcessRequest` I have an error which says:

> no suitable method found to override

I should use `System.Web.HttpContext` but I can't use it, because of Windows RT. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Try use this:

```
HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://www.domain.com");
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "/YourPath");
request.Content = new StringContent(jsonStringToSend, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);
string json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

now you have a variable called json witch contains the response from the server, and you can process it now.